# How to convert images produced by html canvas to .ai(adobe illustrator) file format in either frontend or backend process?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django, canvas, adobe

I'm developing a webapp to edit photos and trying to download them as adobe illustrator (.ai) file format.

The webapp has two parts frontend and backend. React for frontend, and Django restframework for backend.
The photos are edited within a html canvas element, and the canvas is controlled by JavaScript.

Th code below converts the canvas element to a dataURL, so I can see the compiled image after hitting the url. The url shows it is png format.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
```

And the url looks like this.

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAA...
```

Is there any way to convert the canvas image to .ai(adobe illustrator) file format using ether JavaScript, React for frontend, or python for backend process?

Comment: What benefit is there of converting it to an AI file? The user won't be able to edit specific nodes (or your image at all), so an image will be of no difference to the user.

Comment: Actually, my client wants to do this. The produced image will be sent to printing companies, and some of them only accept .ai file format. I don't know why they want it as .ai file.

Comment: I'm not sure how you'd manually do this, but a quick google search led me to [Convertio](https://convertio.co/jpg-ai/), which has an [API](https://developers.convertio.co/). Who cares if it costs though, have your client pay. (They don't have a Python wrapper, but if you see the docs all you need to do is POST the endpoint and you're good to go.)

Comment: Thanks! Looks like that works, but I just need to pay some money huh. If it is possible I'd like to know what kind of algorithms, libraries, or techniques are used behind [Convertio](https://developers.convertio.co/). But this is one of options, thanks!

Comment: I know Convertio only for Google search, and I have no idea how they do it, sorry. Also, I'm wondering, why are you paying the API instead of the client since they wanted it? ;)

Comment: Oh, I mean eventually my client will pay if I use that. Or I pay first then my client will pay me the price for that plus the service fee for me.